# XML query on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm very new to XML query and having trouble with the query below.
Can anyone help me, please?

I am not getting any data from the query below. But somehow I figured that that removing the row `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` from XML data works fine.

However, the original XML data contains this row. Hence, not sure how to write correct SQL.

```
create table xmltest (col xml null)
insert into xmltest values('
<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="-//XBRL International//DTD XHTML Inline XBRL 1.0//EN">
    <ix:nonnumeric contextref="CurrentAccumulatedQ3Instant" name="tse-ed-t:DocumentName">aaa</ix:nonnumeric>
    <ix:nonnumeric contextref="CurrentAccumulatedQ3Instant" format="ixt:dateerayearmonthdayjp" name="tse-ed-t:FilingDate">bbb</ix:nonnumeric>
    <ix:nonnumeric contextref="CurrentAccumulatedQ3Instant" name="tse-ed-t:CompanyName">ccc</ix:nonnumeric>
    <ix:nonnumeric contextref="CurrentAccumulatedQ3Instant" format="ixt:booleantrue" name="tse-ed-t:TokyoStockExchange">ddd</ix:nonnumeric>
    <ix:nonnumeric contextref="CurrentAccumulatedQ3Instant" format="ixt:booleanfalse" name="tse-ed-t:StockExchange" />
</xml>
')
select 
T.Col.value('fn:local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),
T.Col.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
from xmltest
cross apply col.nodes('
declare namespace aaa="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL";
//xml/ix:*'
) as T(Col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty close.

You are declaring the used namespaces. But you forgot to *use* it. Add the `aaa:` to the `xml` and it will return values:

```
select 
T.Col.value('fn:local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),
T.Col.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
from xmltest
cross apply col.nodes('
declare namespace aaa="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL";
//aaa:xml/ix:*'
) as T(Col)
```

Btw: Don't use the *deep search `//`* when you don't need it, one `/` is correct here.

I'd suggest do change this like here:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
                           ,'http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL' AS ix)
select 
T.Col.value('fn:local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),
T.Col.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
from xmltest
cross apply col.nodes('/xml/ix:*') as T(Col)
```

This will define all namespaces in advance. And you can omit the default namespace (just as the original does).